# Code sharing in School of Haskell

Tags: haskell

I looked through the tutorial on [School of Haskell](https://www.fpcomplete.com/) and maybe I missed it but I did not see how to share code between active Haskell elements?

For example in the below `a` is shared between two other active Haskell elements.

````
``` active haskell shared
a = 2
```

``` active haskell
mian = print $ "a: " ++ show a
```

``` active haskell
b = 3
mian = print $ "a*b: " ++ show (a*b)
```
````

This would allow an author to add comments to a ghci like session with out considerable code repetition.

The [BlogLiterately-diagrams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/BlogLiterately-diagrams) package offers such functionality as you can see in the example on it's [hackage page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/BlogLiterately-diagrams).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't miss anything: the feature does not currently exist. We're planning on adding it in not too long.

Comment: Thanks looking forward to it.